# How to Override remove() method in java.util.Iterator

Tags: java

I am given an interface List.java that defines the List ADT and contains methods that a class I am writing (LinkedList.java) must implement. One of the methods is remove().

Within List.java it writes:

```
/**
 * Removes the head (first element) from the list and returns it.
 * @return the removed element from the head of the list, null if the list is empty
 */
E remove();
```

I have also written a class Node.java that represents an individual node in LinkedList with two instance variables, data and next (with getter and setter methods).

In my LinkedList class there are two instance variables, int size (# nodes in LinkedList) and Node  head (reference to head node in LinkedList). So far, for overriding the remove() method I have:

```
public E remove() {
    if (head == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        Node<E> current = head;
        Node<E> previous = null;
        while (current.getNext() != null) {
            previous = current;
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        Node<E> previousNext = previous.getNext();
        E currentData = current.getData();
        previousNext = null;
        size--;
        return currentData;
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error that says:
Error: The return type is incompatible with java.util.Iterator.remove().

I have a very poor understanding of this unit and can use all the help I can get.

*Edit: java.util.Iterator is imported

Comment: Show us the rest of the class and the exact error

Comment: The `List` interface you were given is not the same as `java.util.List`, or `java.util.Iterator`, both of which have `remove` methods that work differently from the method you're trying to implement.

Comment: You're probably implementing the wrong `Iterator` interface.

Comment: `Iterator.remove()` has a `void` return type.

Comment: `LinkedList extends LinkedListIterator` is just wrong.  Do not extend your iterator class in your list.

Comment: @LouisWasserman extending the iterator class is what was causing my problem. Thank you for helping me.